# Nonacademic Letter of Recommendation for Masters

Tags: graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I've been working as a TA for an on campus program for the last year and a half. The director really likes me; she has a Masters in Mathematics and runs the learning services program for the STEM programs but she doesn't teach or do research.

I'm planning on applying to Master's in Computer Science programs and want to eventually do work in mass education programs (like Khan Academy or Coursera). Would it be acceptable to ask for a letter of recommendation from her?

I figured it would be "different" in a good way; also, any other letters would be "average" at best. I was a good student but not much more in my classes.

Comment: "She likes me" doesn't say much.  Has her experience with you given her confidence that you would succeed in a masters program in computer science?  Can she give specifics that computer scientists would find convincing?  That's what an admission committee wants to see.

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe that she has confidence that I will definitely succeed in the masters program but will probably put emphasis on my affinity to better education.

Comment: _Master's in Computer Science_ — Which kind? Professional / course-based / terminal masters, or research / thesis masters?

Comment: @JeffE Terminal Course-based masters looking to go into mass education/industry. Looking to work for a company similar to edx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on the university, for instance on my university the hierarchy of letter of recommendations goes like this:

- Top priority: Faculty (same/different institution)
- Mid: Staff (on same institution)
- Low: High-school Instructors

Of course having faculty give you letters of recommendation is better.
Just remember that "usually" you need 2-3 letters of recommendation.

I would suggest to use the letter of recommendation from this director that you mention, **If and only if** you cant get letters of recommendations from faculty.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good way to strengthen your application.

Also, there is something you can do to strengthen the other potential letters.  If you get to know a professor from a class you have taken, by going to office hours at least once, to show interest in the professor's research, and share something about yourself, the professor will be able to write a slightly less cookie-cutter letter.

Answer (score 0):

The stakes are usually a little lower for masters programs, so this might be okay. If the primary funding source at your new program is a TA-ship, then your experience teaching could count in your favor. Its better if the teaching experience is directly in your new research area. Your reader wants to know that you are ready to start developing more specialized skills in your research area. If you're teaching in that area, then it shows that you understand the basic issues well enough to break them down for a less sophisticated audience. That's good. Make sure the writer really focuses on your engagement with CS more that your engagement with the students. Ask your writer to describe the areas that you were teaching on, and how you handled the material or broke it down, how you dealt with answering questions when you didn't know the answer (did you do research? That's grad level thinking). Have her give examples. Also ask to avoid using feeling language (e.g., she is a caring an compassionate teacher) or personality characteristics (e.g., she is very enthusiastic). If she hasn't written many letters, then she might not know to avoid this.

I will also note, as someone with somewhat eclectic credentials, "different" is rarely a good thing in academic. The goal is to have her tailor the letter to align you as closely as possible with your discipline.